# customize Codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-pagination

Is there a way that I can make codeigniter only display "« Older Articles" and "Newer Articles »" instead of displaying page numbers and all the other stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two ways you can achieve that:

- Modify the CodeIgniter's pagination class
- Make your own library class
- Make some function(s) to achieve that.

If you can modify the CI' pagination class, go with that, but I won't recommend that
because you will need it with same purpose elsewhere possibly.

A better option is to create your own library for that if you can. If you can not do so, you are can make your own functions to achieve that.

Also check to make sure that there might be such thing available already somewhere on the internet's jungle.

Comment: He can extend the Pagination class.

Comment: Thanks, I just copied the pagination library into my applications folder and then remove the parts where it creates the numbers.